# How to add text field to inputAccessoryView and make the textView first responder

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextfield

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rectFake = CGRectZero;

    UITextField *fakeField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:rectFake];

    [self.view addSubview:fakeField];

    UIView *av = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39.0)];

    av.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(200.0, 4.0, 400.0, 31.0);

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0];

    textField.delegate = self;

    [av addSubview:textField];

    fakeField.inputAccessoryView = av;

    [fakeField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

I tried to add

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder]
```

at the end, but it does no work.

Another problem that delegate method to hide keyboard when ENTER is pressed does not work also.

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: try this UIView *av = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 39.0)];

Comment: Sorry I did not mention that it's for iPad and this view stretches along keyboard, so width does not make sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was facing the same challenge. Your (and my initial) approach probably don't work because the text field in the `inputAccessoryView` refuses to become first responder as the `UITextField` is not located on your screen initially.

My solution: check when the keyboard (and with that the accessory view) appear!

Step 1) Listen for the notification (make sure this code is executed before you want to receive the notification).

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(changeFirstResponder)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

Step 2) When the keyboard has appeared, you can set the textfield in your `inputAccessoryView` to become first responder:

```
-(void)changeFirstResponder
{
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];  // will return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing and your idea sounds like it might work, however how do you tell the keyboard to appear in the first place?
I have a UIButton that when pressed I need the keyboard to show with a text field in the accessory view.

Comment: @Darren I know one semi-dirty workaround and that's to have a (hidden) textfield in your current view already and use the button action to set `[yourHiddenTextField becomeFirstResponder]`

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed up doing. Thx

Comment: When I call `[textField resignFirstResponder];` after pressing the done button the input accessory view slides down to the bottom of the screen and stays there. Do I need to remove it from the view manually then?

Comment: @MobileOverlord You shouldn't have to. Are you using ARC?

Comment: Tom, I'm not sure if that's a good idea using NSNotification. If I had another text field on the view and I tap on it, wouldn't your code interfere with the other text field I tapped on? The hidden text field method works fine, all I did was add hidden text field, then on button tap, I call my method to make hidden text field first responder, then immediately set the inputAccessoryView text field as first responder. No need for NSNotification observation whatsoever.