# UITextView Not Become Responding From Another UITextView Accessory View iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, becomefirstresponder

I am working on a message based iPhone app. I have a screen to reply to a received message. This screen contains two UITextViews like bottomTextView and topTextView.

**topTextView is added as bottomTextView's InputAccessory view**.

When the user enter into the screen **`topTextView` has to becomeFirstResponder**. It is showing but the cursor is not placed in the topTextView. The cursor is located in the textview `bottomTextView`. How to make topTextView become first responder with cursor in place?

Here is the code i have tried:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];            
    bottomBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 380, 320, 40)];
    bottomBarViewImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"toolbarbg~iphone.png"];
    [bottomBarView addSubview: bottomBarViewImage];
    [self.view addSubview: bottomBarView];

    bottomTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 7.5, 210, 25)];
    bottomTextView.delegate = self;
    bottomTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    bottomTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    bottomTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [bottomBarView addSubview: bottomTextView];

    topBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 380, 320, 40)];
    topBarViewImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"toolbarbg~iphone.png"];
    [topBarView addSubview: topBarViewImage];

    topTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 7.5, 210, 25)];
    topTextView.delegate = self;
    topTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    topTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    topTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [topBarView addSubview: topTextView];

    [bottomTextView becomeFirstResponder];
    [bottomTextView setInputAccessoryView: topBarView];
}

-(void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(textView == bottomTextView)  
    {
        bottomTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;

        [topTextView becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

The `topTextView` with `topBarView` is showing but the cursor is not placed in topTextView. Could you please help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi ! you were define the delegate in .h file??

Comment: @ParasJoshi yes i define UITextView Delegates in .h file. If the user clicks on bottomTextView the topTextView becomeFirstResponder with cursor inside. But when the user enters into the screen i have to do the same. welcoming your idea's thanks.

Comment: The problem is when we enter into the screen i have to show topTextView as entering input textview. It is showing on the bottomTextView's InputAccessoryView. The InputAccessoryView showing with topTextView but topTextView not becomeFirstResponder to get messages from user. I hope you understand my problem? Your thoughts welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may be because you call `[topTextView becomeFirstResponder];` in UITextView's delegate `textViewDidBeginEditing:`. So the topTextView only becomes first responder when you start editing `bottomTextView`. Try calling `[topTextView becomeFirstResponder];` instead of `[bottomTextView becomeFirstResponder];` in viewDidLoad. See how it goes. I'm not sure, but `becomeFirstResponder` may not call `textViewDidBeginEditing:`. Not sure it'll work, but worth the try...

**EDIT :**

I found a related problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334563/how-to-add-text-field-to-inputaccessoryview-and-make-the-textview-first-responde). It may be because the textView does not appear right away, so it can not become first responder. Here is the accepted answer, by @Tom :

> My solution: check when the keyboard (and thus the accessory view)
>   appeared!
>
> Step 1) Listen for the notification (make sure this code is read
>   before you want to receive the notification).

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(changeFirstResponder)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

> Step 2) When the keyboard has appeared, you can set the textfield in
>   your inputaccessoryview to become first responder:

```
-(void)changeFirstResponder
{
    [textField becomeFirstResponder]; //will return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I have tried but still the topTextView showing but cursor responding to bottomTextview only. And also i have tried using "textViewShouldBeginEditing:" delegate.. Any idea?

Comment: Do you enter *textViewDidBeginEditing:* ? Place a breakpoint at the first line of that method, and check if you are going through it.

Comment: Yes i tried debugging with break points. The control entering into the condition if(textView == topTextView) but topTextview not becomeResponder. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding *topTextview.canBecomeFirstResponder = YES;* in your viewDidLoad ?

Comment: Thank you friend. But, i have added topTextView as InputAccessoryView of bottomTextView right. I will try your idea and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry friend. Even bottomTextView not becomeFirstResponder. Keypad not showing.

Comment: OK, so you might cancel that, lol. I'm updating my answer, I found something that might help. i'll comment when I'm done editing.

Comment: ya thank you friend. I will wait for you and am also trying my level best. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes thank you. I will try it out. I keep to update my result to you. Thanks again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16781/discussion-between-gopinath-and-rdurand)