# how to distinguish between two callers of a notification?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

I had the same problem described here [How to add text field to inputAccessoryView and make the textView first responder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334563/how-to-add-text-field-to-inputaccessoryview-and-make-the-textview-first-responde) and the solution posted by Tom works well. Now my new problem is that the same inputAccessoryView is used by an UITextField and an UITextView and have not yet found a way to distinguish which is the caller.

here is a little code:

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titleField;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *reviewField;
```

in the viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.titleField.inputAccessoryView = self.accessorView;
    self.reviewField.inputAccessoryView = self.accessorView;
    self.accessorView.delegate = self;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(changeFirstResponder:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(fillAccessorView:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
}
```

and the two handlers

```
- (void) fillAccessorView:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    self.accessorView.titleLabel.text = @"MY Title";
}

- (void) changeFirstResponder:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    [self.accessorView.textInputField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

I've already tried like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(changeFirstResponder:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:self.titleField];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(fillAccessorView:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:self.titleField];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(changeFirstResponder:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:self.reviewField];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(fillAccessorView:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:self.reviewField];
```

This way the handlers where never called :/

Does anyone have idea of ​​how to do?

Comment: how are you posting the notifications?

Comment: in selector send the details of the class object. which give details of caller

Comment: @NikitaP: No the textfield / textview is posting it for me :(

Comment: @SatishKAzad can u provide some code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, those notifications have a nil object parameter, so that's why your attempts to  have an object argument didn't work. Instead of using these notifications, you could use the text field and text view delegate methods (textFieldShouldBeginEditing or textFieldDidBeginEditing, and their text view equivalents). Both of these delegate methods are called before the keyboard notifications are received. Remember to make your class the delegate of both the text field and text view.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately I need to know when the keyboard appears on the screen to fill in some fields (especially the textView called "reviewField") present in inputAccessoryView associated with the textField / textView. Then I need to know what was the number in order to update the text.

One solution that I have experienced is to store, using their delegated the 2 field textFieldDidBeginEditing and textViewDidBeginEditing, the object passed in a property "currentField" that is used when I close the keyboard to update it back, but i'm not very enthusiastic about that

Comment: @Alex75, I think you'll have to do something like that though. I don't see any other way.

Comment: ooook :( so i'll check your answer ... hope apple will do something about that soon :(